# Golang: Ordering map by slice in Go templates

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a question about how to order a map by a slice in Go Templates and if it is possible.

Problem: I have a slice of ordered variable names that I want to display on a website, accompanying them I have a map of metadata of variable information that I would like to display together with the variable.

If I have the following struct that I pass in to the template:

```
type Data struct {
       Variables    []string
       Information  map[string]int
}
```

I would iterate over the slice and pass the variable name in to the map

```
{{ range $v := .Variables }} {{ index .Information $v }} {{ end }} // Doesn't work.
```

Here's a Go Playground with the example.
https://play.golang.org/p/AL2csnXdoU

**Question: How can I do this?**

I am fairly new to Golang. Thankful for any input.

Comment: {{ range $v := .Variables }} {{ index **$**.Information $v }} {{ end }} is what I had to do with the original code

Answer (score 2):

The following should work. To access `.Information` inside `range`, you should use `$`, which is basically `d` in your Playground example.

```
{{ range .Variables }} {{ index $.Information . }} {{ end }}
```